# Closing remaining drag and drop thumbnails

Tags: x11, xorg, gnome, window-manager, gtk

I'm using Vooya (a GTK+ program to view raw images). It supports drag and drop, so I can drag the image from the window to the desktop. During the dragging, it shows a small thumbnail/icon of the image under the mouse cursor. So it creates an Xorg window for the drag and drop.

[image: screenshot]

Sometimes these small windows remain on the desktop, and don't disappear, even when Vooya is closed. They are always in front of normal application windows, and clicking on them actually clicks on what is behind them. So selecting them with xkill also doesn't work.

It there a way to close these stray windows, without logging out, or closing the Xorg session?

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Does `wmctrl -l` list those windows? Or `xdotool search . getwindowname %@`? Or `xdotool search '^$' getwindowpid %@` ?

Comment: solved it using `xdotool`. some instances of `vooya` were staying open in background, even though the unity didn't show it

Comment: Great! Please write an answer explaining exactly which commands work for you.